# Python: Ray-trace a WGS84 point with heading and distance

Tags: python, polygon-creation, circle, geofencing

One of my services defines geofences for a mobile app. The geofences consists of a lat/lon pair and radius in meters, in `JSON`, e.g.:

```
{
    "geofenceId":"geofence_b39da38cff7be4b4693cbc31b2394bbb",
    "latitude":32.083611,
    "longitude":34.806111,
    "radius":15000.0
}
```

I would like to display these geofences in KML. Alas, [KML files don't feature circles](https://developers.google.com/kml/faq#circle), so I have to approximate using a polygon with `n` vertices. Each vertex location is the head of a vector originating at the centre of the circle, whose length is the circle radius and has a given heading:

[image]

What's the Pythonic way to calculate `P2` from `P1`, `θ` and `radius`?

**Update:**
I've found some obvious solutions (like [this](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/04/27/converting-miles-to-degrees-longitude-or-latitude/)), which assume that the earth is a perfect sphere. I calculated a circle with a radius of 15 Kilometers and 72 points. For each point, I've calculated the exact vincenty distance from the center. The minimum and maximum are:

```
14941.7356806
15014.5884245
```

The error is significant - a few dozen meters. I would like to find a solution that uses a better approximation.

**Second Update:**

I am trying to calculate ray tracing, which is `(P1_lat, P1_lon, radius, heading) -> (P2_lat, P2_lon)`. This is different from the distance between two given points, which can be easily done with [geopy's vincenty formula](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84885/whats-the-difference-between-vincenty-and-great-circle-distance-calculations).

Comment: Check out first answer [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3264/using-geodesic-measurements-for-circle-radii). And, you mean "I am trying to calculate ray tracing," right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ library [geographiclib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/) has been implemented in Python. Ray tracing, or more accurately - the [*Geodesic Direct problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae#Direct_Problem), is as easy as:

```
geodesic.Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(lat1, lon1, azimuth_degrees, distance_meters)
```

Let's test the accuracy:

```python
from geographiclib import geodesic
from geopy.distance import vincenty

lat1, lon1 = 32.074322, 34.792081         # Azrieli Centre, Tel Aviv

distances=[]
for degree in range(360):
    result=geodesic.Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(lat1, lon1, degree, 15000)
    lat2, lon2 = result["lat2"], result["lon2"]
    distances.append(vincenty( (lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)).meters)

print min(distances), max(distances)
```

Gives:

```
14999.9999876 14999.9999999
```

The accuracy is between 5 and 7 digits, which is great for my needs.

Links:

- [geographiclib in PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geographiclib)
- [A list of geographiclib implementations](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/) (C, Fortran, Java, Python, JavaScript, Matlab, IDL and C#)