# Does PostGIS have a Vincenty Distance calculation?

Tags: postgis, great-circle, geopy, vincenty-formulae

I have compared some distance calculations between [`geopy`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84885/whats-the-difference-between-vincenty-and-great-circle-distance-calculations) and [PostGIS `ST_Distance_Sphere`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance_Sphere.html), and it seems that PostGIS `ST_Distance` uses a calculation that is similar to the great circle distance rather than Vincenty.

#### Geopy Vincenty (Most accurate) using `geopy`

```
>>> from geopy.distance import great_circle, vincenty
>>> p1=(32.083659,34.806480)
>>> p2=(32.0843373,34.8065365)
>>> vincenty_distance = vincenty(p1, p2).meters
>>> print vincenty_distance
75.4044140365
```

#### Great Circle (less accurate) using `geopy`

```
>>> great_circle_distance = great_circle(p1, p2).meters
>>> print great_circle_distance
75.6324224394
```

#### PostGIS `ST_Distance_Sphere`, Unknown Algorithm:

```
=> SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(
          ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(34.806480, 32.083659), 4326),
          ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(34.8065365, 32.0843373), 4326));
 st_distance_sphere
--------------------
       75.611223453
(1 row)
```

**Does PostGIS have a Vincenty Distance calculation?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use ST_Distance_Spheroid, or use a cast to the geography type

```
SELECT ST_Distance('POINT(34.806480 32.083659)'::geography, 
                   'POINT(34.8065365 32.0843373)'::geography);
```

Hard to tell from the coordinates you are using, but make sure the longitude comes first, the latitude comes second in the POINT syntax.