# Calculating length of Appalachian Trail

Tags: postgis, length

I'm new to GIS and wanted to start play around with some data about the appalachian trail (AT) and PostGIS.

However I already failed at the first and most simple task to calculate the length of the AT. I downloaded the data [here](http://www.appalachiantrail.org/home/explore-the-trail/gis-data). And imported it using the pgShapefileLoader. After loading I noticed that the srid of at_centerline wasn't set. Inspecting the table with `select st_astext(geom) from at_centerline limit 1` showed that it was in lat/lon format. Therefore I updated the table with `select updateGeometrySRID('at_centerline','geom',4326)`.

So, time to calculate the length

```
select sum( st_length( geography( geom ) ) ) / 1000 * 0.621371 
from at_centerline
```

yielded 2122.61779398273 miles. However the AT currently is 2190 miles long.

I also tried to directly calculate the length in miles with this query

```
select sum( st_length( st_transform( geom, 2877 ) ) ) / 5280 
from at_centerline;
```

which yielded 2126.50802521765 miles.

**So how to explain the discrepancy?** Is it simple the data provided by the ATC isn't accurate enough? I would rather doubt that. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are measuring distances on flat ground. **Maybe** the 2190 miles is considering the slope?

Comment: There seems to be an elevation of around 88 Miles. Using Pythagorean Theorem I get 2124.4 miles considering elevation. This doesn't seem to be the error.

Comment: the SRID of 2877 is a colorado state plane CS..why would you use that?

Comment: Because I didn't read this answer thoroughly and only copied the query: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143436/how-do-i-calculate-st-length-in-miles

Comment: up-down, up-down, up-down... that adds up much more than going straight from start to the highest point

Comment: @JGH that isn't the highest point. it is the "Approximate Gain/Loss in Elevation"

Comment: I just read that the ATC also distributes its data in NAD83 (also lat/lon), which might make a little difference. Maybe check the metadata of the shapefiles. A cast to geography usually results in more precise/realistic measures, as it calculates the distance based on the spheroid. Depending on your PostGIS version, this defaults to WGS84. If your data is in NAD83, you'll need to transform to WGS84 first. But in general, I doubt that you will get exactly to the 2190 miles...who knows how they measured that lenght?

Comment: @ThingumaBob The projection is probably `GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]`

Comment: that should be NAD83 (EPSG:4269). update your geom column to that and transform to WGS84 to use the geography type.

Comment: @ThingumaBob So I updated my table with `select updateGeometrySRID('at_centerline','geom',4269)` and queried with `select sum(st_length(st_transform(geom, 4326)::geography))/1000*0.621371 from at_centerline` and still get 2122 miles

Comment: sorry, yes, using updateGeometrySRID actually transforms the datas SRID from its current to the one given (both 4326 in your case, so nothing changed...). what you want is to make sure that you either imported your data with the correct one or, if none is set, set it to the right one.

Comment: @ThingumaBob Ok, so I reimported the dataset and set the srid from 0 to 4269. Still no difference

Comment: well...assuming the SRIDs are correct, I suspect that there is not much more you can do. theoretically adding the 80 miles in elevation gain/loss gets you closer, but as I said, who knows how they measured the lenght. could be with different data, different projections or by car. I thought you could get closer with the right CRS, but apparently no. nevertheless: you played a lot with PostGIS, can't say you didn't learn ,)

Comment: @ThingumaBob Thank you very much for your help, appreciate it! I wasn't expecting to get to the exact length the ATC uses. However, starting from the same dataset, arriving at a difference of 70 Miles is way to big.

Comment: what about st_distance_spheroid?
 take the two end points of the linestring and compute the distance??...https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109562/does-postgis-have-a-vincenty-distance-calculation

Comment: @ziggy wouldn't that leave out all the turns, since a geom data contains a multilinestring?

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes good point, didnt think of that. just trying to brainstorm

Answer (score 2):

You should find out how the data was collected - was it :

1. Traced via satellite image - if so, it will not include the ups and downs and curves of the earth, etc. - you'll be calculating the length of the linestring as it was digitized in 2D space
2. Collected via GPS - this would give the length including the ups and downs as it was walked and collected in 3D space

Also:

I don't think simply converting this data to 'geography' (versus geometry) are going to help you here based on the first set of issues above.

Also: check this [State Plane Map](http://www.avenza.com/sites/default/files/flashmaps/spsc/), the trail crosses multiple zones, so transforming the geom to State Plane won't work - so you'll likely have to convert to SRID/EPSG 2163 ([US National Atlas Equal Area](https://epsg.io/2163)) - which is in meters - unless someone has a better equal area coordinate system to use.

(sorry you got hung up using the Colorado State Plane value - I posted that answer you referenced!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and no worries for my confusion with the colorado state plane. That was entirely my fault. As far as I know the use GPS devices to collect the data every once in a while. However some data is "corrected" via satellite images. I'll try to reach out to someone who created the shape file.

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes good stuff!

Comment: @DPSSpatial I tried your suggestion with 2163 with this query  select sum(st_length(st_transform(geom,2163)))  from at_centerline

Comment: @ziggy how did the results compare?

Comment: i got this huge number..3419158.44452333. is 2163 measured in degrees?

Comment: @ziggy metres (meters?) as per https://epsg.io/2163

Comment: true, well in that case i got 2124 miles

Comment: @ziggy have to wonder where the 2190 is coming from vs. the distances postgis is calculating on the linestring...data collection is the issue, I think!

Comment: @DPSSpatial The 2190 is stated here: http://www.appalachiantrail.org/home/explore-the-trail and also here https://www.amazon.com/Appalachian-Trail-Data-Daniel-Chazin/dp/1944958002 and my personal copy of The AT Guide also lists 2190 miles. But IIRC The AT Guide uses different data then the ATC