# Which spatial-reference system is used by the Haversine formula?

Tags: coordinate-system

I've been reading [Pro Spatial with SQL Server 2012](http://www.apress.com/9781430234913?gtmf=s).  It discusses the various spatial-reference systems (SRS) that can be used when defining a coordinate system.  According to the book, Google uses [WGS 84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System).

Prior to my exposure the SQL Server's functionality (i.e. `Geography` data type), I've used the Haversine formula to calculate distances between two lat/lng pairs.  I'm assuming that it (the Haversine function) makes some assumptions about the Earth's geoid (perhaps the `great-circle distance`), which suggests that it is using a particular SRS.  Is this correct?  Could one make use of other SRS (at least ones that use lat/lng pairs) with the function just by changing the `great-circle distance`?

** edit **

Said another way, does the Haversine formula care is the coordinates are WGS84, NAD83, or another other geodetic datum?

Comment: The haversine formula computes great circle distances on a sphere. The 'r' in the equation (if using [Wikipedia's formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)) is the radius of the sphere.

Comment: A more accurate formula is [Vincenty's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae) which factors in the fact that the earth is an ellipsoid

Comment: The errors made when using the Haversine formula to compute geodetic distances are analyzed in the closely related thread at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25494. Their magnitudes are so enormous compared to the differences between WGS84, NAD83, or any whole-earth geodetic datum, that one could justify answering this question in the negative.

Comment: So, the errors from using a spherical datum (Haversine) when compared to the other shapes (WSG84,NAD83) far outweigh the errors that are introduced by using a lat/lng pair from any of these other datum with the Haversine function.  Is this correct?  Was the Haversine function designed w/ a particular coordinate system in mind?

Comment: Haversine is correct *only* for spherical coordinates (latitude or colatitude, plus longitude) on a perfect sphere.  Haversine is a formula: it's not a datum.  It is inappropriate to apply it to geodetic coordinates relative to an ellipsoidal datum, but it is a decent approximation to the extent the ellipsoid can be considered to be perfectly spherical.